# Plotting data from input file from command line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have been given a data file called "density_air.dat" and i need to take the data from each column and put them into their own lists (ie tList will hold the values in column starting with "-10" and density will hold values in column starting with "1.341".  The lists then need to be plotted.  I am having trouble populating the lists with this data...any help?

```
from scitools.std import *
import sys
import pylab as pl

inFile = sys.argv[-1]

f = open(inFile, 'r')

for x in range(4):
    f.readline()

tList = []
density = []

for line in f:
    words = line.split()
    for x in words:
        tList.append(words[x])
        density.append(words[x])

f.close()

plot(tList, density)
```

The data file is:

```
# Density of air at different temperatures, at 1 atm pressure
# Column 1: temperature in Celsius degrees
# Column 2: density in kg/m^3 

-10     1.341
-5     1.316
 0     1.293
 5     1.269
10     1.247
15     1.225
20     1.204
25     1.184
30     1.164
# Source: Wikipedia (keyword Density)
```

Comment: When you loop over `words` (why is it called `words`, by the way?) you get strings and then you try to access list elements using those strings which should generate: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: I dont really have a specific reason other than the sake of calling the variable but i do get that error.  How can i convert the values into a float or integer?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `numpy` function called `loadtxt` which loads ascii files into `numpy` arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import sys

inFile = sys.argv[-1]
temperature, density = np.loadtxt(inFile,unpack=True)
plt.plot(temperature, density,'ko')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the loop to:

```
for line in f:
    words = line.split()
    tList.append(int(words[0]))
    density.append(float(words[1]))
```

Because code can quickly get obfuscated using numerical indexes you can use tuple unpacking to assign the values to meaningful variable names, e.g.:

```
for line in f:
    temp,dens = line.split()
    tList.append(int(temp))
    density.append(float(dens))
```

Comment: After fixing this code i am not thrown any errors however when i try to print the lists to check the contents, it returns empty lists

Comment: Something elsewhere in the code is wrong then. I tested that this code does what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

You use pylab for plotting, so why not for reading in?

```
import sys
import pylab as pl

inFile = sys.argv[-1]
temperature, density = pl.genfromtxt(inFile, unpack=True)

pl.plot(temperature, densitiy, 'rx')
pl.show()
```

`unpack=True` is needed because your data is aranged in columns.
`'rx'` draws red crosses, as you do not want to connect points.

The function `genfromtxt` is part of `numpy` which is loaded with pylab.

I would recommand to not use pylab but load the respective modules yourself, in this case `matplotlib.pyplot` and `numpy`:

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

inFile = sys.argv[-1]
temperature, density = np.genfromtxt(inFile, unpack=True)

plt.plot(temperature, densitiy, 'rx')
plt.show()
```

And don't use `from ... import *` if you have more than 1 import